# Calling javascript function in iFrame from parent with postMessage

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, postmessage

The intent of the following code is to call some function window.name1.function1(val) within #pm-frame with "someVal" as an argument.

However, when I try calling window.location.assign("someUrl") by `ExecFcn(["location","assign"], "someUrl",...)`
I get an "illegal invocation" error when the iframe tries to call the function.
I'm assuming this has something to do with the fact that I am creating a copy of the function and am losing some necessary information along the way? It looks like the scope is not changing though, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

PARENT DOC

```
var fcnReference = ["name1","function1"]; // define the function reference
ExecFcn(fcnReference, "someVal", function (data) {
            // do something 
        });
...
function ExecFcn(pNames, pValue, pCallback) {
    // setup the data to pass to the child iframe
    var eventData = {
        eventId: "windowFcn",
        data: {
            names: pNames,
            param: pValue,
            callback: pCallback
        }
    };
    // post the data to the frame
    PostEvent(eventData);
}
function PostEvent(e) {
    iframe = document.getElementById('pm-frame');
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(e, "*");
}
```

IFRAME:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (e) { // message received
  var evt = e.data;
  switch(evt.eventId)
  {
   case "windowFcn": // if the eventId is a request to run a function
      // build the reference
      // ["name1","fcn1"] => window.name1.fcn1()
      var fcn = window;
      $(evt.data.names).each(function(i,p){
         fcn = fcn[p];
      }); 

      var op = fcn(param); // throws illegal invocation

      postData = {
         eventId: "windowFcn",
         data: {
             callback: evt.data.callback
             output: op
         }
      }

      parent.postMessage(postData,"*");
      break;
   }
```